# I Cannot Choose Build on App Store Connect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, app-store, app-store-connect

I try to upload my app on App Store, but I can't choose the build file

[image]
[image]

I already do the uploading process and match the version on XCode but still there is no build that I can choose.
[image]

Is there any step that I missed?

Comment: Check the Testflight tab and see if the build is still in processing state

Comment: @alvAro365 There is no build in testflight tab. here is the screenshot https://imgur.com/zksqFeE

Comment: same issue, did you able identify the solution?